# replacing the cursors with set based

Tags: cursors, set-based

I have sql script with a lot of cursors which take too long to execute.I need to replace them with set based operations. I can't understand how can replace them and having the same results.Here is part of the code:

SET @CurAddress = Cursor static local FOR
select did, isnull(StreetType.Cid,0) , isnull(StreetType.Abrev,'Street')  from EntityAddress left join StreetType
on EntityAddress.AddressTypeCid = StreetType.Cid where EntityDid=@entityId
OPEN @CurAddress
FETCH NEXT FROM @CurAddress INTO @entityAdressId, @streetTypeCid, @Street
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @Street = @Street + ' ' + cast(@streetTypeCid as varchar(max)) + ' ' + @entityTypeAbrev + ' ' + cast(@entityNumber as nvarchar)
UPDATE  EntityAddress set Street=@Street where Did=@entityAdressId
--print @Street + ' ' + cast(@streetTypeCid as varchar(max)) + ' ' + @entityTypeAbrev + ' ' + cast(@entityNumber as nvarchar)
FETCH NEXT FROM @CurAddress INTO @entityAdressId, @streetTypeCid, @Street
END
CLOSE @CurAddress
DEALLOCATE @CurAddress

I tried to replace the cursors by:

```
                    UPDATE ea
        SET 
        Street = CONCAT(st.Abrev, ' ', CAST(ea.did AS VARCHAR), ' ', et.Abrev, ' ',                     CAST(e.EntityNumber AS NVARCHAR))
        FROM EntityAddress ea
        JOIN Entity e ON ea.EntityDid = e.did
        LEFT JOIN StreetType st ON ea.AddressTypeCid = st.Cid
        JOIN EntityType et ON e.EntityTypeCid = et.Cid
        WHERE e.did = @entityId
```

But I think that this only does an update and nothing else...

Thanks in advance,
Paulo Dias

Comment: Stumbled across this through "set-based" tag. This needed a SQL tag, something to indicate the RDBMS in which this was written. Query needed to be formatted to be legible. The question makes little sense, as all the cursor loop does IS to perform an update. User's first and only question, we'll probably never see them again, unfortunately.